# Changing the value of a variable's reference in java

Tags: java, variables, reference

I'm not sure if the title is the best, but what I want to do can be illustrated in this example

```
class TestClass {
    public String foo = "foo"

    public void makeFooBar() {
        String bar = foo;
        bar = "bar";

        System.out.println(foo); //should print "bar"
    }

}
```

This is obviously a contrived example, but it illustrates the point. I want to change the value of foo by changing the value of bar that references foo. is that posible?

Comment: You could if you would warp it, so it becomes an object. But plain field refference linking doesn't exist in java.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to change my code so it doesn't require that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a way if you want to update a certain value in multiple places (e.g. by using a wrapper object). Of course there are waay more fancier ways to accomplish something simular.

```
class TestClass {
    public Wrapper<String> foo = new Wrapper("foo");

    public void makeFooBar() {
        Wrapper<String> bar = foo;
        bar.set("bar");

        System.out.println(foo); //should print "bar"
    }

     public static class Wrappper<T>
    {
          T value;

         public Wrapper(T value)
         {
               this.value = value;
         }

         public T get() { return this.value; }
         public void set(T newValue) { this.value = newValue; }
         @override
         public String toString() { return value.toString(); }
    }
}
```

Basically any primitive type cannot be passed by reference. Althoug String is technically not a primitive type, java does treat it a bit more special. (Reading upon Internal Stringpool would give you a nice insight. In this page there is a nice explanation including some visual examples: http://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool)